# Animation Rendering In 2.79

Tags: rendering, animation

So, i was making a jumpscare animation, then i realised they changed the rendering stuff A LOT. I'm talking about "Output". It seems that we can only use "FFmpeg Video" as the output for rendering animations. I watched some videos to see what the settings should be for it and how to at least render the thing.
But theeen, my animation came out really low resolution, the details look crappy, very crappy.

I would LOVE to get some help, in any ways, doesnt matter. I just really need help with this.

Comment: Have you changed the settings in the `Encoding` panel to your needs? Higher output quality, as well as lower Keyframe intervals, give better results. (By the way: for any animation that takes more than 10 minutes to render, I'd suggest using the [Frame sequence workflow](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/workflows/animations.html), i.e. render frames first, check that they look like they should, possibly edit them and then assemble the animation: see the link for details)

Comment: Yes! I did change the Encoding to my needs. I watched this video for the settings https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CrpWJZsZpBk If it is wrong for a detailed animaton i'd love for you to tell me. Also i will be trying out the Frame Sequence workflow right now. I really feel like it will still screw up the quality but i'll try.

Comment: is the render resolution at 100%?